# Buddypress: Remember pagination for Membersloop in URL

Tags: ajax, wordpress, buddypress

How to remember the currently opened page in the pagination of the membersloop in Buddypress, so when visiting a profile and coming back to the membersloop, it gets opened on that page?

I saw that in buddypress-nouveau.min.js?ver=1.7.8:formatted the ajax call is done via the JS function objectRequest() but it gets called with the "page: 1" parameter as a fixed value.

Is there a way to override this?